# Any linux RDAP client available?

Tags: rdap

I was looking I think everywhere and thought that here it may be the quickest.

Where can I get any **RDAP client**?

Is it actually in use by anybody?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

3 years passed - could not find any client.

I think the answer is then : **NO, no reliable client is available now**.

Comment: Define "reliable". You were given a least two clients: `nicinfo` and `rdapper`. What does not work with them in your view? You also have the Go client at https://www.openrdap.org/

Answer (score 3):

You can use rdapper written in Perl:

```
git clone https://github.com/jodrell/rdapper
cd rdapper
perl Makefile.PL
make
sudo make install
sudo cpan JSON
sudo cpan JSON::Path
sudo cpan MIME::Type
sudo cpan Mozilla::CA
rdapper
```

But I've not found any domain/IP, that rdapper can procceed.
Another app, that I had tried is nicinfo written in Ruby:

```
git clone https://github.com/arineng/nicinfo
cd nicinfo
bin/nicinfo com
```

Comment: I just tested `nicinfo`, which seems to be published by ARIN. Looks like it works. You can also install it with: `gem install nicinfo`.

Answer (score 1):

`RDAP` is still a new protocol today, as used by RIRs already, but not very much yet by domain name registries. So things change fast.

Have a look for example at https://www.openrdap.org/

Also this website: https://about.rdap.org/ will give you various useful pointers.

PS: you do not specify your needs for using RDAP not the language you are using